# changing a Node name which has values with Xslt

Tags: xslt

Sorry that i have kept very less information.

I am getting a XMl response which have nodes with same Node Name. I need to rename all the Node name if its repeated.

The XML response i an getting is like shown below.

```
<Envelope>-
  <Body>-
    <getItemResponse>-
      <status>
        <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
      </status>-
      <item>-
        <item>
           <originOfData>SME</originOfData>-
           <itemNumbers>
              <shortNumber>115632</shortNumber>
              <tssArticleNumber>PT0401450-T46N</tssArticleNumber>-
              <itemMainGroup>
                <code>P</code>
                <description>Piston Seals</description>
              </itemMainGroup>-
              <itemSubGroup>
                <code>PT</code>
                <description>Turcon Glyd Ring® T</description>
                </itemSubGroup>-
              <relatedItems>
                 <alternateItemsNumber>ORAR00428-N7083</alternateItemsNumber>
              </relatedItems>
           </itemNumbers>-
           <itemDrawing>
             <drawingNumber> </drawingNumber>
           </itemDrawing>
           <description1>PT0401450-T46N.</description1>
           <description2>Turcon Glyd Ring® T</description2>-
           <dimensions>
              <insideDiameter>124</insideDiameter>
              <outsideDiameter>145</outsideDiameter>
              <width>8.1</width>
           </dimensions>-
           <weight>-
             <uom>
                <code>KG</code>
                <name>Kilograms *</name>
             </uom>
           </weight>-
           <primaryUOM>
              <code>PC</code>
              <name>Pieces *</name>
           </primaryUOM>-
           <material>
             <materialCode>T46N</materialCode>
           </material>
        </item>
      </item>
    </getItemResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

You can see the Nodes Item, code, Description are repeated more than once. I need to change the Node name if its repeated by adding a number to it. Like Item node to Item1.
So the Nodes which are repeated will be changed to Item, Item1, code, code1, code2, code3.
But the description need to change to description-1, since the description1 is already there.
For this purpose i have used XSLT which transform the node to the required name. I am calling this function using three variables Root, OldNode and NewNode.

The function is called repeatedly with desired node name. The function looks like below.

```
RemoveGetItemNamespace(Source : DotNet "System.Xml.XmlDocument";VAR Destination : DotNet "System.Xml.XmlDocument")
XslTransform :=  XslTransform.XslTransform;
XMLStyleSheet := XMLStyleSheet.XmlDocument;
XMLStyleSheet.InnerXml(

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
'<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">'+
'<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>' +
'<xsl:template match="@*|node()">'+
'<xsl:copy>'+
'<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>'+
'</xsl:copy>'+
'</xsl:template>'+
'<xsl:template match="'+Root+'">'+
'<xsl:variable name="oldNode" select="'+OldNode+'"/>' +
'<xsl:variable name="newNodeXml">' +
'<xsl:element name="'+NewNode+'">' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*|node()"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/child::*"/>' +
'</xsl:element>' +
'</xsl:variable>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($newNodeXml)"/>' +
'</xsl:template>' +
'</xsl:stylesheet>'
);

XslTransform.Load(XMLStyleSheet);
writer := writer.StringWriter();
XslTransform.Transform(Source, nullXsltArgumentList, writer);
Destination := Destination.XmlDocument;
Destination.InnerXml(writer.ToString());
```

The have called the function to change the first item node to item1 like shown below.

```
//ChangeNodeName(XMLDotNet,XMLDotNet,'/Envelope/Body/getItemResponse/item','/Envelope/Body/getItemResponse/item','item1');
```

It was successfully changed the Node name to Item1.But I tried same function to change the code to code2 for the child of itemSubGroup. But it deleted the value of the code node. like shown below.

```
-<itemSubGroup>
  <code>PT</code>
  <description>Turcon Glyd Ring® T</description>
</itemSubGroup>

-<itemSubGroup>
  <code2/>
  <description>Turcon Glyd Ring® T</description>
</itemSubGroup>
```

i think i need to change the code some what to keep the value.

```
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*|node()"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/child::*"/>' +
```

Instead of calling the function again and again. can you please guide me to create a function (XSLT code) to rename all the node at once. Please help me guys. Thanks

I have corrected the Code by giving an extra line

```
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*"/>' +
```

below the code

```
'</xsl:template>'+
'<xsl:template match="'+Root+'">'+
'<xsl:variable name="oldNode" select="'+OldNode+'"/>' +
'<xsl:variable name="newNodeXml">' +
'<xsl:element name="'+NewNode+'">' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*|node()"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/child::*"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*"/>' +
'</xsl:element>' +
'</xsl:variable>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($newNodeXml)"/>' +
'</xsl:template>' +
```

But i need one function to change the repeated name space at once. Please help me.

Comment: Your xml-file and xslt attempt are missing.

Comment: To add code, simply add it to the text box, highlight it, then click the `{}` button to format it as code (which will simply add 4 spaces to the left of each line). This will allow you to show any 'angled brackets' of XML.

Comment: Thanks Guys, i was stuck with how to post my question.

Comment: Please try again, without the `'` and `+` garbage.

Comment: I am using a Dot-net transform functionality. for which i am creating a style sheet which will transform the response XML to my requirement and give the out as the new response. Its working also but i need to call function repeatedly for changing the Node names. I want to make it easy by adding an index number to it. Like second item node will change to item-2, second code will change to code-2, code-3, description to description-2 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to change the Node name if its repeated by adding a number to
>   it. Like Item node to Item1. So the Nodes which are repeated will be
>   changed to Item, Item1, code, code1, code2, code3.

First of all, this is a really bad idea. Alike items names should be identical, otherwise processing them becomes very difficult, if not impossible. If you need to add sequential numbering, use an attribute - that's what they are for.

Now, to perform this task purely in XSLT 1.0, you could do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="same-name" match="*" use="name()" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[count(key('same-name', name())) > 1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="num">
            <xsl:call-template name="index-of">
                <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="key('same-name', name())"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- proc template -->
<xsl:template name="index-of">
    <xsl:param name="node-set"/>
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($node|$node-set[$i]) = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$i" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count($node-set) > $i">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="index-of">
                <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="$node-set"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following **test input**:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <item/>
        <item>
            <property/>
            <property/>
            <property/>
        </item>
    </item>       
    <item>
        <item/>
        <not-item/>
        <item>
            <property/>
            <property/>
            <non-property/>
            <property/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <property/>
            <property/>
        </item>
    </item>       
</items>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item num="1">
      <item num="2"/>
      <item num="3">
         <property num="1"/>
         <property num="2"/>
         <property num="3"/>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item num="4">
      <item num="5"/>
      <not-item/>
      <item num="6">
         <property num="4"/>
         <property num="5"/>
         <non-property/>
         <property num="6"/>
      </item>
      <item num="7">
         <property num="7"/>
         <property num="8"/>
      </item>
   </item>
</items>
```

--

Note:
Subject to your processor's support, this could be streamlined by using some EXSLT functions.

---

### Edit:

> I am trying to import the xml to my application. In my application two
>   element cannot have same node name.

If that is the real problem here, it can be solved much more simply and efficiently by attaching a unique id to all element names - without considering if the element is "repeating" or what is its position in document order:

**XSLT: 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '-', generate-id())}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The exact result is somewhat processor-dependent. When applied to the above test input, Saxon 6.5 will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items-d0e1>
   <item-d0e2>
      <item-d0e3/>
      <item-d0e4>
         <property-d0e5/>
         <property-d0e6/>
         <property-d0e7/>
      </item-d0e4>
   </item-d0e2>
   <item-d0e8>
      <item-d0e9/>
      <not-item-d0e10/>
      <item-d0e11>
         <property-d0e12/>
         <property-d0e13/>
         <non-property-d0e14/>
         <property-d0e15/>
      </item-d0e11>
      <item-d0e16>
         <property-d0e17/>
         <property-d0e18/>
      </item-d0e16>
   </item-d0e8>
</items-d0e1>
```

Other processors may generate ids in a different format, but they all will be unique within the processed document scope.

Comment: The problem is with the Node name like in my case. you can see the node name Item is repeated twice. I am trying to import the xml to my application. In my application two element cannot have same node name. if i change the node name (xml format is fixed) i can create my xmlport according to it. I have never tries the attribute with it. will try that. thanks

Comment: @PrajeeshNair If you really need this, you can use the same method to append the *index-of* number to the element's name, instead of creating an attribute. Just use `<xsl:element>` instead of `<xsl:copy>` and calculate the new name.

Comment: @PrajeeshNair BTW, if all you need is to make the element names unique, you could simply append the unique id generated by the XSLT processor to the existing name - without going through all the trouble of sequential numbering.

Comment: Sorry michael, i am new to xslt. tried to change as you told but didn't work out. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @PrajeeshNair Please clarify: would appending a unique ID (not necessarily a sequential number) to the element names work for you?

Comment: Hi Michael, The Response will be having an exact structure i have mentioned above, But in my application a node name cannot repeat even it has a different attribute. So i want to change the Repeated node by adding an index like 2,3.... But the description which is repeated has already description 1 and description2. so for making thing easily i would like to add -1,-2,... to all the node names which are repeated. according to this i can design my XML port (my application). Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I see your XSLT already makes use of the Identity Template, which is good as that means you only need to add templates for the elements you do wish to transform in some way. I am not entirely clear what elements you do wish to transform, but you mention changing "Item" to "Item1". In this case, just add the following template

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
    <Item1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Item1>
</xsl:template>
```

And similarly for changing "code" to "code2" you would add this

```
<xsl:template match="code">
    <code2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </code2>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <Item1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Item1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <code2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </code2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, if you really did want to build your XSLT up dynamically via a string so you can have different element names, it should not be hard to do, although there are other more 'friendly' ways of doing this.....

Comment: Thank you Tim, Sorry for my incomplete Question

Comment: I have done it by adding this codes 
'</xsl:template>'+
'<xsl:template match="'+Root+'">'+
'<xsl:variable name="oldNode" select="'+OldNode+'"/>' +
'<xsl:variable name="newNodeXml">' +
'<xsl:element name="'+NewNode+'">' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*|node()"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/child::*"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*"/>' +
'</xsl:element>' +
'</xsl:variable>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($newNodeXml)"/>' +
'</xsl:template>' +

Comment: If you are saying you there are multiple "code" elements, and you want to change the first to "code1", the second to "code2", the third to "code3", and so on, then your current approach is not at all suitable for this. I would suggest you edit your question to show a slightly smaller XML input sample, and also the output you expect, which has repeated elements. I think there are easier ways to achieve this, without the need for dynamically building up XSLT from a string. Thank you!